# contentDocument.documentURI alternative to IE6 and IE7?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to grab the URI of an iframe after "load" event. I have used contentDocument.documentURI so far, but it does not work in IE6 and IE7. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All browsers support *contentWindow.location.href*.